# Button outside SVG not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have inside a button an animated SVG with some javascript, both have to be clickable BCS. of the animation and the state of the button itself which I need to handle.

can somebody help me

here you can see the full code in codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-field-uyvvcr?file=/src/App.js

```
  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState(false)

  const mouseEnter = () => {
    if (!activeFilter) {
      setActiveFilter(true)
    } else {
      setActiveFilter(false)
    }
    console.log(document.querySelector('object'))
  }

  return(
    <div className='search__container'>
      <div className='search'>
        <input placeholder='Search' type='text' />
        <button onClick={mouseEnter} className={`${activeFilter? 'active ' : ''}filterButton`}>
          <object type="image/svg+xml" data={FilterIcon} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more details? There is an animation on the SVG when you click it. Should it also animate when you click the button or are we talking about two different actions on the SVG and the button? Can you make a reproducible example where it is clear what is not working?

Comment: currently if you click at the button, just the SVG animation / function is triggered, 
if you click at the border, only the button is triggered, 

I would need on click on the Button that both are triggered,
SVG & button component

inside the codesandbox you can see the issue 
if button is clicked there should fire a function and a border should be added
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-field-uyvvcr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

### Why does this happen?

The html `object` element creates a new browsing context (you can see if you inspect with the developer tools: notice an embedded `#document` under `object`). The click event captured within the svg fires and bubbles up this context, but never goes beyond it. As a consequence, it never reaches the button element.

### How to solve?

You don't want to have two browsing contexts. In order to do so, you can simply get rid of the `object` and insert the svg as a direct child of the button.

#### For your particular case of using react

You could use svg as react component:

```js
<button onClick={mouseEnter} className={`${activeFilter? 'active ' : ''}filterButton`}>
  <FilterIcon />
</button>
```

You may want to investigate [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/).

Hopefully, as it seems you are using `create-react-app`, it should come for free.